# updating a JSF outputtext in panel a from backing beans (a status bar concept)

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a page with a menubar and a header and message xhtml pages.  I want the header page to display specific information like a status bar does.  This status bar needs to be updated at different program points thru out the entire app.  What is the best way to accomplish this in primefaces. Here is my main.xhtml page.  I have tried putting a outputtext in the header.html but it only posts one time when main.xhtml is displayed.  I need it to display via a call from a backing bean and update the message.xhtml.  I am not trying to display validation messages.  I tried using messages but it's not what I am looking for.  I am trying to put up a one or two line dashboard above my menubar that will display specific data for example when the user is editing a project ( project/risk management tool) the dashboard would display which project is being edited while the content page has all the fields in the project.  this way the user knows what project they are working on.

```
    <h:body>
<ui:include src="/pm2/IdleMonitor.xhtml" />
<div id="page">
    <div id="header-container">
        <div id="header">
            <ui:insert name="header">
                <ui:include src="header.xhtml" />
            </ui:insert>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="messages-container">
        <div id="messages">
            <ui:insert name="messages">
                <ui:include src="messages.xhtml" />
            </ui:insert>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="menu-container">
        <div id="menu">
            <ui:insert name="menu">
                <ui:include src="/pm2/MenuBar.xhtml" />
            </ui:insert>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content-container">
        <div id="bodyContent">
            <ui:insert name="bodyContent">
                Main content
            </ui:insert>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer-container">
        <div id="footer">
            <ui:insert name="footer">
                <ui:include src="footer.xhtml" />
            </ui:insert>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Read about push concepts…

Comment: thank you,  I thought it might go that way.